# 3rd Party Libraries and Py2exe

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, exe, py2exe

How would I go about bundling, say, Beautiful soup into an exe along with my code using py2exe?

The code I am using for my setup.py right now is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# equivalent command line with options is:
# python setup.py py2exe --compressed --bundle-files=2 --dist-dir="my/dist/dir" --dll-excludes="w9xpopen.exe"
options = {'py2exe': {
           'compressed':1,  
           'bundle_files': 1, 
           'dist_dir': "exe/dist/dir"
           'dll_excludes'  }}

setup(console=[''], options=options,zipfile = None)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `options` you can add an attribute `includes` and add the libraries that way. An example:

```
options = { "py2exe": {
                "includes": ["LIBRARY HERE", ...]
          }}
```

This includes external libraries that haven't already been found by Py2exe. If I remember correctly, Py2exe should try to find the dependencies on it's own and any it doesn't find you can use the above method.

I'm not sure about the library structure for Beautiful Soup as I've not used it, but an example would be:

`"includes": ["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"]`