# Py2exe doesn't find bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup, py2exe

In my original code, I have the line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When I use py2exe, it builds fine but further up in the output it says:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['_scproxy', 'bs4']
```

I specifically put bs4 in the py2exe options:

```
"includes": ["bs4.BeautifulSoup"]
```

Is that how I should be referencing BeautifulSoup in the includes statement?
The fella over here didn't know how to do it either: [3rd Party Libraries and Py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770046/3rd-party-libraries-and-py2exe)

Do I need to use packages instead of includes or something? All regular libraries and some other like mechanize import fine, but I can't get BeautifulSoup to work fine. Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: I solved part of this by uninstall BeautifulSoup and re-installing with --always-unzip option:

```
easy_install --always-unzip beautifulsoup4
```

However, it added 9 new missing modules. One being '_scproxy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is that you have your **setup.py** in the *same directory* as your module and your are running it from *that directory*.

If that doesn't work your should add your module to your path in **setup.py**:

```
module_path = r'path\to\your\BeautifulSoup\module'
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(modules_path)
```