# Building an executable file for python code using py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I installed "py2exe" for "Python2.7" , made a "Hello World" program, used py2exe to build its exe and it worked perfectly.

Now when I tried building the exe of my actual code, the folders get created and exe is also created without any problem but when I launch the exe the console appears for less than a second and closes.

Only difference in this case and test program is that I have multiple code files in this case and in some of them I am importing a few files/libraries as well
Following are import commands spread across different files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
from RdWrtCls import *
import os
import openpyxl
```

Initially my source code was :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
setup (console =['Crawler.py'])
```

when this didn't work I did some research and found that sometimes there is a missing dll problem, so I modified my code to this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
data_files = [("Microsoft.VC100.CRT", glob(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\redist\\x86\\Microsoft.VC100.CRT\\*.*'))]

setup(data_files =data_files,console =['Crawler.py'])
```

I am stuck in this problem so any and all sorts of help would be highly appreciated.

Other Information:
I am using:
Windows7, 
Python 2.7-32 bit

Update : 
 I found a suggestion in a question on stack overflow for a similar problem suggesting to run the EXE through command prompt. I ran the program through command prompt and showed me the error

```
Import error : No module named bs4
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167026/py2exe-doesnt-find-bs4

Comment: There was problem with packages , things worked out when I reinstalled them. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully build a working exe. Following are the steps I took I hope they prove helpful for others facing these issues in future.

1) Launch the program Using Command Prompt so I can view errors.

2) Put all my code(functions,classes) in main file.

3) reinstalled latest version of pip

4) Uninstalled and reinstalled BeautifulSoup4 using pip

```
pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4
pip install  BeautifulSoup4
```

5) Now "jdcal" started giving problems (it is installed when installing openpyxl)

6) Uninstalled openpyxl using pip

7) Uninstalled jdcal using pip

8) reinstalled openpyxl using pip (it automatically installed jdcal )

9) Now exe runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My project also failed at jdcal.  I was successful in just the last steps of B-Abbasi:

6) Uninstalled openpyxl using pip
(on Win7: pythonXX\Scripts\pip uninstall openpyxl)

7) Uninstalled jdcal using pip

8) reinstalled openpyxl using pip (it automatically installed jdcal )

9) Now exe runs perfectly.