# Cannot run generated .exe with py2exe

Tags: python, openpyxl, py2exe

I am trying to generate aa .exe using py2exe for a python script that generates an excel. Here is just a sample code. I am writing value 100 to a cell and saving the excel to Users Desktop using openpyxl. This works perfectly fine when I run it directly.

```
import openpyxl
import getpass

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet('test')
ws.cell(row=1, column=1, value=100)

username = getpass.getuser()

wb.save('C:\\Users\\{}\\create_exe\\gen.xlsx'.format(username))
print 'Done'
```

And when I compile it using py2exe it compiles also just fine.
The problem arises when I run the generated .exe file. I get a return saying 
`ImportError: No module named jdcal`

setup.py file is as follows

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

packages = ["openpyxl", "openpyxl.workbook", "xml.etree", "xml"]
excludes = []

setup(console=['test_program.py'],
      options={"py2exe": {"excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages}}
      )
```

Thisngs I have already tried

1. I have searched and few people said Install openpyxl using pip. I
   have done that and pip says its alöready installed.
2. I have also tried to install jdcal using pip and pip says it is installed.
3. I have uninstalled jdcal and installed it using pip and manually, and
   still the same error.
4. I have included jdcal in the packages and still no change in the outcome.

I hope someone can help me with it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :
Generated Filed in dist folder are as follows (openpyxl cannot be seen here, I don't know why)

1. tcl (Folder)
2. _ctypes.pyd
3. _elementtree.pyd
4. _hashlib.pyd
5. _multiprocessing.pyd
6. _socket.pyd
7. _ssl.pyd
8. _tkinter.pyd
9. bz2.pyd
10. pyexpat.pyd
11. select.pyd
12. unicodedata.pyd
13. win32ui.pyd
14. numpy.core._dummy.pyd
15. numpy.core.multiarray.pyd
16. numpy.core.multiarray_tests.pyd
17. numpy.core.operand_flag_tests.pyd
18. numpy.core.struct_ufunc_test.pyd
19. numpy.core.test_rational.pyd
20. numpy.core.umath.pyd
21. numpy.core.umath_tests.pyd
22. numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.pyd
23. numpy.linalg._umath_linalg.pyd
24. numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.pyd
25. numpy.random.mtrand.pyd
26. _win32sysloader.pyd
27. win32api.pyd
28. win32pdh.pyd
29. win32pipe.pyd
30. tk85.dll
31. tcl85.dll
32. libiomp5md.dll
33. pywintypes27.dll
34. python27.dll
35. w9xpopen.exe
36. pythoncom27.dll
37. library.zip
38. test_program.exe (Executable File)

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually include it in `setup.py` in `packages = ["openpyxl", "openpyxl.workbook", "xml.etree", "xml"]`
so it would be:
 `packages = ["openpyxl", "openpyxl.workbook", "xml.etree", "xml", "jdcal"]`

Comment: @ Maxoz99, Thank you for replying. I have tried that also. See my point number 4. When I try to do it, then while running setup.py, I get the error. So the .exe file does not get generated.

Comment: @daanav Ah sorry my bad, overread it. Maybe try to use a different tool for example pyinstaller or cx_Freeze and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: @daanav Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766435/building-an-executable-file-for-python-code-using-py2exe) says uninstall and install `openpyxl` using `pip`. Try this as well, if you haven't yet.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re installing it with pip. But now pip for me is blocked as our university is using a proxy that they are not letting me use with pip. So the only options I have now is to uninstall using pip but install using the setup.py file with openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have had good luck letting py2exe detect the modules that are needed.  I've never tried to specify every module necessary.
try this:

```
   from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test_program.py'])
```

this should be run from command line as

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

py2exe outputs .dll files in the dist directory, these have to be in the directory that you run your .exe file from.  if you just want one .exe file and no .dll files try this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    console = [{'script': "test_program.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

this should be run from command line as

```
python setup.py
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it the same way also, letting py2exe determine the modules and dlls for me. It generates the exe but when the exe is run, it returns the Import Error

Comment: Could you edit your post and describe the full contents of the dist folder that is output by py2exe?  also, delete the dist and the build folder every time you compile as it seems to have an effect on the output if the folder exists already.

Comment: Added the list.

Answer (score 0):

I use [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) and never had any issues. 
Here's the setup.py for a cx_freeze file

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"excludes": ["html5lib"],"optimize":2}
setup(name = "App Name" ,
      version = "1.0.0.0" ,
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      description = "" ,
      executables = [Executable("FooBar.py")])
```