# No module named beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, py2exe

I'm trying to use py2exe to convert a python script into a .exe, but I get the error no module named 'BeautifulSoup'. I have BeatifulSoup 3 and 4 installed. I also tried [BS4.BeautifulSoup] and [BeautifulSoup4]

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'strange.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['BeautifulSoup'],
        }   
    }
)
```

Comment: does it work when directly executing it as python?

Comment: From bs4 import Beautifulsoup works in the Python command line.

Comment: You're importing from `bs4` from the repl, so use `bs4` in your config.

Comment: You mean use 'includes': ['bs4']? Because that gives me the error 'no module bs4'

Comment: Did you try `'includes': ['beautifulsoup4']`?

Comment: beautifulsoup4 gives me the error 'no module named beautifulsoup4'

Comment: Sorry I meant `beautifulsoup4` like jbihan pointed out. What I was getting at is that you mentioned `BeautifulSoup4`, but the package name is `beautifulsoup4` (notice the capitalization).

Comment: How did you install it? How are you executing your setup script? How are you starting the python repl?

Comment: Well I tried both with and without capitalization and both don't work. Thanks for trying to help though. I installed beautifulsoup with pip. I'm trying to execute the setup script through the Windows command line using C:\users\me\desktop\setup.py py2exe. I'm not sure what python repl means.

Answer (score 1):

The following thread should provide the solution to your problem.

[Py2exe doesn't find bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167026/py2exe-doesnt-find-bs4)

Apparently, py2exe does not support compressed eggs, so the key is to uninstall BeautifulSoup and reinstall with --always-unzip option:

```
easy_install --always-unzip beautifulsoup4
```