# jar or exe file from Sikuli python script

Tags: python, jar, exe, sikuli, sikuli-script

I just started doing some scripts with Sikuli in Python.

I would like to know if it's possible (and if yes, how) to create a jar or exe file from my python script (file .py and images).

I would like to easily run my program from other machines that do not have sikuli install (e.g., `java -jar my_script.jar` or `my_script.exe`) or give the utility to some colleagues, but I don't want that they see the source code.

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: I think in this case I still need the sikuli (run setup.jar) to each machine

Comment: No, converting your script to executable will do the job. All that is needed for it to run will be packaged into the executable.

Comment: I was able to convert a simple python script in exe thanks to the py2exe. Unfortunately I don't know how to pack all the requred data for my sikuli program. In a folder a have: the sixulix.jar, the python script ("sikuli_test.py") and all the images. How my setup.py should be? Now it's like this: from distutils.core import setup;   import py2exe; 
    setup(console=['sikuli_test.py'])

Comment: You might want to include the needed jar in your *setup.py*, something the like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770066/4121573). Otherwise you could create a shallow java Main, and create an executable fat jar from it including the sikuli library. (especially if you will run it from Linux, I doubt a *.exe* will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a jar file, as [Sikuli is written in Java and uses Jython](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#how-to-use-this-document). You need to do three things in order for this to work.

### Get Sikuli jar:

First get the `sikuli-java.jar` file ([step-by-step instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22932283/3745896)), which you can get by downloading [`sikuli-setup.jar`](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.0.1/+download/sikuli-setup.jar), and run it using options 4 (only Java) and 6 (all OS compatible). This should download the `sikuli-java.jar` file.

### Distribute your script itself as a jar:

#### Obfuscated Version:

You can compile your Python using Jython ([full instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15939006/3745896)):

```
$JYTHON_HOME/jython $JYTHON_HOME/Lib/compileall.py python_src/
```

where `python_src` is the directory containing all your `.py` files.

Then you can call these compiled files (which look like `myFile$py.class`) from Java, using a wrapper class (see full instructions for an example).
This wrapper calls a single Python method, so you can just make that method be your main Python method that kicks off the rest of your program.

Compile the wrapper class:

```
javac -cp $JYTHON_HOME/jython.jar TestJ.java
```

Then [`jar` all your `.class` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209860/3745896):

```
jar cvfe myapp.jar <packageName>.TestJ *.class
```

where `<packageName>` is the package for your wrapper `TestJ.java` class.

You'll need to add Jython to this jar as well. Just follow the first few steps of the "Python .py files in jar" section below, or [download the standalone Jython jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar) and include it the same way as `sikuli-java.jar` in the "Combine the jars" section below.

#### Python .py files in jar:

Now you have to create the jar for your script itself. The [full instructions are here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255113/3745896), but if you want a summary:

> Take the `jython.jar` file that you get when you install Jython and zip the Jython Lib directory into it, then zip your .py files in, and then add a `__run__.py` file with your startup logic (this file is treated specially by Jython and will be the file executed when you call the jar with `java -jar`).

There is also a [more general guide](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts) from python.org if you prefer.

**Note:**
The full instructions above assume you have the `zip` program. If you don't, you can use `jar uvf jythonlib.jar Lib` instead of `zip -r jythonlib.jar Lib` (and do similar wherever `zip` is used). [See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386777/convert-jython-scripts-to-jar-file)

### Combine the jars

You can simply add `sikuli-java.jar` to the jar containing your scripts using `jar` as [mentioned in the note above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386777/convert-jython-scripts-to-jar-file). You can also [combine the two jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080283/3745896) (also using `jar`) if you prefer.

Either way, this should give you a single jar file that can run your Sikuli program across any system with a compatible JVM. Run it using

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Congratulations, you're done!

<sup>See the [stack overflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255113/3745896) or the [full Python guide](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts) if you need to deal with command line arguments, or generally need more detail.</sup>

Comment: But in this way I cannot "obfuscate" the code, right?  I would like to distribute my program hiding the source code as much as possible

Comment: @user3472065 sure you can! Jython is already compiled to Java eventually, you can just use the Jython compiler (jythonc) to turn your .py flies into bytecode *before* putting them in the jar. I’ll add a section about it.

Comment: Now I have my SikuliScirpt.class. I did not understand this step => "Then you can call these compiled files (which look like myFile$py.class) from Java, using a wrapper class (see full instructions for an example). This wrapper calls a single Python method, so you can just make that method be your main Python method that kicks off the rest of your program."  I never develop anything in java, could you explain step by step what I should do?

Comment: @user3472065 if you go to the full instructions for the obfuscated version there’s an example of the class that you can just use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to convert a .py to .exe and excetra

While I believe it is possible to change the extension, the process would be much easier and smoother if you use an extension to python, like Py2exe the download to which can be found with a simple google search (I have also included a link to their site below). The program will allow you to convert the program into a .exe and will run without needing a python installation.

Here is a list of reputable and good options: http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging_a_python_program

I would personally recommend Py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/) and the tutorial to Py2exe can be found here (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17883649)

Comment: Ah okay, im new to this site so thank you for this. Will edit some of my answers, thank you.

Comment: I was able to convert a simple python script in exe thanks to the py2exe. Unfortunately I don't know how to pack all the required data for my sikuli program. In a folder a have: the sixulix.jar (needed to make the standalone program), the python script ("sikuli_test.py") and all the images. How my setup.py should be? Now it's like this: from distutils.core import setup; import py2exe; setup(console=['sikuli_test.py'])

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, did you get it to work the way you want it, ie. making it very difficult to gain access to the python source code (although not impossible if an agent really wanted to disassemble your code code)?